# Mediawiki login after upgrade to new version

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I tried to upgrade to a new version of Mediawiki. Old version is 1.30.0. I deleted the files of the old version and copied the files of de new version to that location. I tried both version 1.34.1 and 1.31 LTS.

I follow the web-based installation script. This script also asks to set the administrator user/password. At last the installation script has been walked through without any errors.

But then, when I login to Mediawiki, the dialog says the login is wrong. I tried it several times and I'm 100% sure to login with the user/password I set in the installation script.

It is possible to create a new user, but this user is for example not allowed to delete pages. Because this user is not part of the administrator group.

I read something similar in those old posts:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Tm37jcm4hmuv1ia2
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Rdlhbju6me72rigr

Does anyone has an idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: How did you handle LocalSettings.php file?

Comment: The script provided to download this file, and I put it in the Mediawiki folder where it belongs.

Comment: Have you kept your former database or did you build another? Did you provide the script with the same password as in the previous version?

Comment: I kept the former database. I tried it now with the same password as in the previous version. And it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User and password information is stored in the database. While you updated files and kept the previous database, the installation script left it untouched, and ignored the new user information you provided. So your former user information will still work.